# Matriz bidimensional(NxN) para imprimir numero de abajo hacia arriba

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

```
for(int fila = 0; fila < n; fila++){
            for(int columna = 0; columna < n; columna++){
                if(columna == 0 && fila>0){
                valor++;
                matriz[fila][columna] = valor;
                }//fin if           
            }//fin for intern
        }//fin for externo
```

Mi matriz imprime toda la columna desde 1 a n, lo que quiero es que imprima asi:

1. 0 0 0 0 0 0
2. 5 0 0 0 0 0
3. 4 0 0 0 0 0
4. 3 0 0 0 0 0
5. 2 0 0 0 0 0
6. 1 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Pues iniciar la variable `valor` con el mismo valor de `n` pero en vez de aumentar `(valor++)`aplicas disminuir`(valor--)`

```
    int valor=6;
    for(int fila = 0; fila < n; fila++){
            for(int columna = 0; columna < n; columna++){
                if(columna == 0 && fila>0){
                valor--;
                matriz[fila][columna] = valor;
                }//fin if           
            }//fin for intern
        }//fin for externo
```